# Rspec expects status code 201 but fails on code 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-api

I am using Rspec to test an API, one of my test expects an error code of 201 but fails because it is receiving an unexpected code of 200 the code is as follows:

```
it 'returns status code 201' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
end
```

I want all status 200's to pass the test. What methods should I use? Do I need to create a test helper to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Are you saying that anything in the 200s should pass? This seems odd given that the HTTP Status codes are all distinctly different. 201 is generally returned for a POST request where "a resource" was created; however many APIs will return 200 for anything that went according to plan including creation, updating, general data fetches, etc.

Comment: Yes I would like to make it so that anything in the 200s will ast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it "have success status" do
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
end
```

Matcher message says

```
   expected the response to have a success status code (2xx)
```